# Connect JDBC to IP address

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

I'm having issues connecting to an external IP address using JDBC. When I execute the following code, I get this error `No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://52.206.157.109:3306/U054Jk`

Code:

```
package util;

import java.sql.*;

public class db {
    private static String server = "52.206.157.109";
    private static String dbName = "U054Jk";
    private static String userName = "secret";
    private static String password = "secret";

    private static Connection getCon() throws SQLException {
        String host = "jdbc:mysql://" + server + ":3306/" + dbName;

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                host,
                userName,
                password
        );

        return conn;
    }

    public static ResultSet ExecQuery(String query) throws SQLException {
        //Get the connection
        Connection conn = getCon();

        //Create the statement
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

        //Execute the statement
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        //Return ResultSet
        return rs;
    }
}
```

I can connect with my SQL client just fine using the credentials but can't quite figure out the JDBC string that I need for the URL. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you add mysql jar to buildpath?

Comment: I did not. Is that necessary when I'm hitting a DB at an external IP address? Sorry Java isn't a language I'm terribly used to.

Comment: Java only contains the interfaces of JDBC (the API), it needs an implementation (a JDBC driver) for a specific database to be able to connect to that database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please add [MySQL Connector](https://www.mysql.com/products/connector/) in the classpath. Your project needs a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) implementing the [interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_(object-oriented_programming)) of [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity).

If you are using [Apache Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven), add the following in the [pom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven#Project_Object_Model).

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.13</version>
</dependency>
```

Or else, download the jar from the [link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.13) and add it to the classpath.